# How to revert a commit?

Tags: c#, libgit2, libgit2sharp

I tried looking into every object in LibGit2Sharp, but I was unable to find a way to revert a particular commit. Is it possible to revert a commit in LibGit2Sharp or is it yet undone?

I would have expected something like `repo.Revert(commit.Sha)` or perhaps even `commit.Revert()`.

It could be perhaps possible to achieve this by taking a diff of the changes, and manually creating a blob and committing it?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to revert a commit in LibGit2Sharp or is it yet undone?

Unfortunately, **Revert** is not available yet.

> It could be perhaps possible to achieve this by taking a diff of the changes, and manually creating a blob and committing it?

Indeed, that would be a good starting point, but this would require to "apply/merge" the reversed diff, which might be quite cumbersome and/or error prone when being done "by hand".

### Update

Revert has just been merged in the development branch. See **[Pull Request #706](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/pull/706)** for more details about the API and the test cases.

Comment: I will wait then. Update your answer when it's possible to do with LibGit2Sharp ;)

Comment: @Tower Sir! Done, Sir! The wait is over. Revert is now available in LibGit2Sharp ;)

Answer (score -1):

Well I'm not familiar with libgit2sharp but to undo a commit with git you usually do a "commit --amend" or a "git reset" and there should be a possibility to issue those commands with libgit2sharp.

Comment: I'm looking for `git revert`, not amending commit or resets which are both different from revert.

Comment: @rFactor There is no such think like a "revert" with git.

Comment: @cli_hlt Yes there is. see the **[git-revert](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert)** man page.

Comment: @nulltoken Thats sort of syntactic sugar to commit amend. From the man page: "Note: git revert is used to record some new commits to reverse the effect of some earlier commits (often only a faulty one). If you want to throw away all uncommitted changes in your working directory, you should see git-reset(1), particularly the --hard option. " Note that this is NOT equivalent to what svn users are used to with "svn revert".

Comment: @cli_hlt It's really a little bit more complex than a git amend. One could revert a very old commit and this would had good chances of triggering some merge conflicts. Amending a commit does not rely on merge algorithms.

Comment: @cli_hlt I'm not looking for `svn revert` equivalent. I'm looking for a way to pick any commit in anywhere in the history, negate it, and commit after the current HEAD.